# C++ iteration over list and individual objects

Tags: c++, iteration

I have an STL list of pointers, along with another pointer of the same type. I need to perform a ton of operations on each of them. My current method is to push the pointer onto the list, iterate through everything, then pop the pointer back off. This works fine, but it got me wondering if there were a more elegant/less hacky way to iterate through a combination of things. (say if I had a pile of other additional things to add to the iteration)

The current functional, but a bit hacky way:

```
std::list<myStruct*> myList;
myStruct* otherObject;

//the list is populated and the object assigned

myList.push_back(otherObject);
for(std::list<myStruct*>::iterator iter = myList.begin(); iter != myList.end(); ++iter){

      //Long list of operations

}

myList.pop_back(otherObject);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more idiomatic approach might be to encapsulate your "long list of operations" into a function, then call it as needed. For example:

```
void foo (myStruct* x)
{
    // Perform long list of operations on x.
}

...

{
    std::list<myStruct*> myList;
    myStruct* otherObject;

    // The list is populated and the object assigned.

    foo (otherObject);
    for(std::list<myStruct*>::iterator iter = myList.begin(); iter != myList.end(); ++iter)
    {
        foo(*iter);
    }
}
```

Then, if you later need to apply `foo` to other items, just call as needed.

While there's nothing inherently evil about adding `otherObject` to `myList` in the manner you describe, it is in a way abusing the list and should probably be avoided if possible.

Comment: For this there is an algorithm defined in <algorithm> called for_each. More information about it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/

Comment: @zxcdw: indeed. As I understand it though, the question was about an efficient way to apply a complicated procedure to a list of items as well as a free individual of that type. `for_each` is useful for the first part of that, but I avoided it in my answer to try to emphasise the aspects of the answer that (as I understand it) the OP was most interested in. Definitely worth pointing out though - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
void doStuff( myStruct& object )
{
    //Long list of operations
}

int main()
{
    std::list<myStruct*> myList;
    myStruct* otherObject;

    //the list is populated and the object assigned

    for( auto iter = myList.begin(); iter != myList.end(); ++iter )
    {
        doStuff( **iter );
    }
    doStuff( *otherObject );
}
```